# Sum of positive entries in the set of real numbers

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose I have a set of $n$ real numbers $a_i$ ($i=1,2,...,n$) and I know the following sums
$$ C_p = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i^p} $$
for any integer $p$.

Can I find the sum of all positive $a_i$ neglecting the negative ones?

Comment: Are you working on a specific example (i.e., with specific known values of $n$, and $C_1,...,C_n$?

Comment: @quasi It doesn't matter. I've ment that I can easily calculate any of $C_p$ if it could help. I've tried to find the sum of positive entries by manipulating with $C_1$ and $C_2$ but have failed.

Comment: It _does_ matter. In general, you can't do it _symbolically_. For a specific example, it may be possible.

Comment: @quasi In my specific example I only know that $C_1 = 1$ and $n=16$.

Comment: You must know more, else you can't get the rest of the C's. Please edit your question to give the actual problem, with all the given info.